# Lookup value in mysql select statement

Tags: mysql, select

I've a table1 like this one:

```
ID | IDS_table2
1  | 1,2
2  | 3
3  | 4,5,6
```

and table2 like:

```
ID | Value
1  | Value1 
2  | Value2 
3  | Value3 
4  | Value4 
5  | Value5
6  | Value6
```

I need to select value from table2 in a select statement of table1 to have:

```
ID | Value_tbl2
1  | Value1,Value2
2  | Value3
3  | Value4,Value5,Value6
```

Is is possible?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for an [**`INNER JOIN`**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-inner-joins.htm), although you should certainly split up your IDs in `table1`, probably through a bridging table.

Comment: do you have the ability to split Value_tbl2 into two columns?

Comment: @Obsidian, yes he needs an inner join but first he needs to handle is non proper data.  You should never store comma delimited values in a database.

Comment: Obsidianage is mistaken. You'd benefit from proper normalisation, which is not the same thing.

Comment: Obviously, the best approach is to change db schema. You need to explain, do you need just help with querying data or advice on structuring tables and relations.

Comment: This schema is a pretty blatant violation of the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) of
[database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). If you made a proper relational table it'd be a lot easier to to do the mapping, trivial in fact with a straight `JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

A normalised table might look like this:

```
ID | value_id
1  | 1
1  | 2
2  | 3
3  | 4
3  | 5
3  | 6
```

Comment: your assumption is that Id is not identity

Comment: Octocode. It's not an assumption. Normalisation demands it to be so.

Comment: I cannot modify the DB Schema... I need to fine another solution. A mysql procedure?